# Windows 10 File Explorer crashing regularly

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10, crash

I upgraded to Windows 10 a week ago, and then installed a fresh copy of it on a SSD. Everything worked fine, until File Explorer suddently started to behave weird: When I double-click on a folder, it opens in a new window (despite having "Browse Folders" set to "Open in same window"), and when I copy a file, it freezes for ~10 seconds, after which it crashes and restarts (however, the file is copied just fine). The crash also happens randomly when I browse Control Panel.

Things I tried already:

- Reset Windows. The problem was fixed temporarily, but came back after a couple of days.
- Uninstalled last update.
- Booted in Safe Mode.
- Removed all shell extensions using shexview.

Nothing worked.
The crash event log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          8/30/2015 6:30:18 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      D180-M1
Description:
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.10240.16431, time stamp: 0x55c9bd76
Faulting module name: windows.storage.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16405, time stamp: 0x55b46055
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x0000000000120dec
Faulting process id: 0xc48
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0e3408ef60455
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\windows.storage.dll
Report Id: 3f9927d9-ad92-45c6-a325-dace805f2099
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: 1) What is your antivirus (+version)

2) Do you have a card reader?

Comment: 1) Right now, the out-of-the-box windows defender, client version 4.8.10240.16384 2) No

Comment: Try browsing to a random file in the My Documents folder, select (right-clicking the file) File Properties and open "File History". Wait after it has finished displaying everything, then reboot. Report whether it still crashes after that.

Comment: Still crashes...

Comment: Also, in event viewer, the faulting module name sometimes says ntdll.dll.

Comment: create a crash dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU I'll look at it with a debugger

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A434443E01C7A42E!359&authkey=!ADjRdE398r17Hz4&ithint=file%2c7z

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can you share with what debugger you are looking the dump at so that I can check it too?

Comment: @Jason I use WinDbg. this may be a bug. You get a STACK_OVERFLOW because some parts of code repeat over and over again (**RECURRING_STACK: From frames 0x8 to 0x1**). I've asked Microsoft if they have any information. I'll post here if I get information.

Comment: ok, I got an answer. backup the key (export in .reg file) **Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{93F2F68C-1D1B-11D3-A30E-00C04F79ABD1}** and next rename it. Now look what happens.

Comment: There is no such subkey in NameSpace.

Comment: Can you try safe booting and then report (in safe mode) whether Explorer works? You will find how to safe boot here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/change-startup-settings-in-windows-10#v1h=tab01

Comment: What happened finally? Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I did not solve it, and safe mode doesn't solve it either.

Comment: OK, I will try to analyze the dump more today.

Comment: Try to install the 90day Win10 Trial in a VM and look if this version has the key. If yes, export it into a .reg and import it in your Windows 10.

Comment: This version has exactly the same NameSpace subkeys as mine, the key doesn't exist there either.

Comment: I got the answer that not enough users get the crash with this crash signature so that Microsoft doesn't analyze it in depth.

Comment: Well, that's sad, but understandable. Do you know what exactly causes my bug?

Comment: nope, because Microsoft hasn't analyzed it in depth.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. It seems that what caused it for me was trying to customize explorer using command line. I ended up with the copy/move crash, and open-in-new-window issue.

This is the command that broke things for me:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,/root,::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}
```

I chanced upon this case, and it seems that resetting folder options in the registry might keep you from having to do a system restore, or recreating the user. [Here's the related KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813711).

I ended up only having to delete and recreate BagMRU, and Bags (I compared my registry before and after corruption for differences, I also compared to the MS case).

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
```

There were more differences, but this was the first I tried and it solved at least the open-in-new-window issue. I wasn't experiencing the crashing anymore because I had done a system restore.